# ImageMagick convert grey shading only fuzz

Tags: imagemagick

I want to convert to white any light shades of grey.  I am using '-fuzz 10% -fill white -opaque #efeaee'.  The problem is that the fuzz converts other colours other than grey, not just shades of grey (ie light yellow and light green get converted).  I have tried to reduce the fuzz and repeat for various versions of grey but it really doesn't work and I'm sure there's a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in ImageMagick, by converting to HSV colorspace. Then threshold the S and V channels. You want low saturation and high value combined as a mask. Then blend the input and a white image using the mask.

[image]

```
sthresh=10
vthresh=10
convert zelda1.jpg \
\( -clone 0 -fill white -colorize 100 \) \
\( -clone 0 -colorspace HSV -channel 1 -separate +channel -threshold $sthresh% -negate \) \
\( -clone 0 -colorspace HSV -channel 2 -separate +channel -negate -threshold $vthresh% -negate \) \
\( -clone 2,3 -compose multiply -composite -blur 0x1 \) \
-delete 2,3 \
-compose over -composite \
result.png
```

[image]

```
sthresh is the fuzz value for how close in color it is to white
vthresh is the fuzz value for how close it is in brightness to white

Values of zero mean exactly pure white.
```

Comment: Thank you.  This looks perfect but I cannot get this type of conversion to work in Powershell?  I have made many other (much simpler) conversions but can't work out how to handle the () or the / in your suggestion above?

Comment: Windows syntax is different. Remove the \ from the \(  and the \). Change the \ to ^. The latter are new line characters. So the command needs to be in new lines. Otherwise, Remove the \ and make the command all one line. Also note that % in a .bat file need to be doubled (escaped) as %%. I do not know how that works in Powershell

Comment: Yes, got it all to work in bat script which I should be able to put in powershell.  It was the double %% that was breaking it.  Thank you!!

Comment: For future reference, the followin is the BAT file but it works exactly the same in Powershell using "cmd.exe /c"     magick convert "9.jpg" ^ ( -clone 0 -fill white -colorize 100 ) ^ ( -clone 0 -colorspace HSV -channel 1 -separate +channel -threshold 3%% -negate ) ^ ( -clone 0 -colorspace HSV -channel 2 -separate +channel -negate -threshold 30%% -negate ) ^ ( -clone 2,3 -compose multiply -composite -blur 0x1 ) -delete 2,3 -compose over -composite  "9-out.jpg"